# Create a sectioned UITableView using NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am trying to create a `UITableView` with two different sections. I know I can group them on an attribute of my managed object. For instance if I'd like to group them per `name` I'd do:

```
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                         managedObjectContext:_context 
                         sectionNameKeyPath:@"name" 
                         cacheName:@"uploadProperties"];
```

And I return the number of secionts like:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [[_fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}
```

The problem though is that I do not want to group it per attribute (such as the name). I want to group them for specific values, namely one part that has `pud_id = 0` and another section that has `pud_id > 0`.

How can I achieve this? Is it possible to use kind of a where clause? Or can I create a property on my managed object and use this in the `sectionNameKeyPath` such as:

```
- (BOOL) hasPudZero {
   if (self.pud_id == 0)
      return YES;
   return NO;
}
```

??

Thanks for your input!

Comment: From previous experience, I found that fetchedresultscontroller is only really useful for very simple queries and that in this case you are probably going to have to bake your own fetch and arrange the two arrays of objects into another ano that can be used in your data source methods.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could create a transient attribute of type NSString that returns one of two strings?

```
- (NSString *)sectionIdentifier
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
    NSString *tmp = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];

    if (!tmp) {
       if (self.pud_id == 0) {
          tmp = @"SectionOne";
       } else {
          tmp = @"SectionTwo";
       }
       [self setPrimitiveValue:tmp forKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

and then use `sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionIdentifier"` when creating your NSFetchedResultsController.  Make sure you set the primitive value of sectionIdentifier back to nil if the value of put_id changes.